# Gitlab can not clone my git projects to the virtual machine

Tags: git, ssl, ssh, proxy, virtual-machine

*(this is my first question here, and apparently its mandatory)*

so, today's problem concern the connection to git from a new VM...
This is how configured git on this machine :

https://gitlabprod.intra.lne.fr/help/ssh/index#see-if-you-have-an-existing-ssh-key-pair
GIT + ssh-keygen generate +

```
eval $ (ssh-agent -s) ssh-add <directory>/ssh-file.ssh
```

```
ssh -T git@giturl
```

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

and this is the error I'm getting

fatal: unable to access 'urltoclone.git/': Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

on other machines I resolved this problem using :

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

has anyone an idea how to solve this ?

thanks a lot !!

on other machines I resolved this problem using :

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: The `407` response code means "proxy authentication required". It sounds like your proxy requests some sort of credentials. But why are you cloning the repository via http after setting up ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.sslVerify false` is:

1. A bad idea, you deactivate the SSL certificate
2. only for HTTPS URL (https://...)

If you are adding ssh keys to the ssh-agent, it is because you want to use SSH URLs

So if you are trying to clone a repository, make sure its URL starts with `git@<yourGitLabServer>`, assuming that your keys have the default names `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.